# how to add a user input area just like Wordpress new post area has?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, user-input

i want to add a user input area just like wordpress new post input area has and with all the tools(eg:- adding hyperlinks, making bold letters, adding a new picture to the post etc..) to my website. Anyone can tell me how do i do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TinyMCE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjFvtP3lvHKAhXMB5oKHdtPDGsQjBAIKTAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tinymce.com%2Fdocs%2Fdemo%2Fbasic-example%2F&usg=AFQjCNGPX8hmd0dNW65Tx6Ex-GrGYwewvQ&sig2=ObVFzTWmunHTsyUmRiQcmA).
It's the extension which provides WYSIWYG. Wordpress is also using TinyMCE.

You need to initialize tinyMCE using javascript:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
  ],
  toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  content_css: [
    '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

and it will make all current page selectors(`textarea`s in example) which are defined in init to be shown with extended tools.

```
<textarea>

</textarea>
```

Comment: What does `WYNIWYG` stand for, Raymon?

Comment: Its stands for **What You Need Is What You Get.** means providing visual tools to create html tags.

Comment: I thought TinyMCE was a `WYSIWYG` editor. Because I sometimes need money and other times food and I know people who need finished, well designed and polished websites. However, TinyMCE fails miserably at delivering those.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu TinyMCE is currently one of bests WYNIWYG editors I know. I like it.

Comment: I like it too, Raymon. But it still delivers only what you ***see***, not what you ***need***. It would be grand if it delivered what you needed. But it's not grand. It's (*only*) great. You're welcome.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu :)) Oh, I got it after your emphasize. I made a mistake. You're right. Thank you for mentioning.